# SI4735-D60 chip no FM signal reception

Tags: rf, frequency-modulation

Trying to tune the [SI4735](https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/data-sheets/Si4730-31-34-35-D60.pdf) chip to an FM station.
Have using this library and example to drive the chip with Arduino UNO and based on the console output from the sketch the control interface works fine: https://github.com/pu2clr/SI4735/tree/master/examples/SI47XX_01_SERIAL_MONITOR

It's going through the FM band but cannot find anything, it's all just noise.

I've a chip on a breakout board with the crystal and capacitors soldered to the breakout board and the breakout board plugged into a solderless breadboard + an op-amp based headphones driver on the breadboard.

**Edit:** I've measured the signal on the crystal and it's as expected - a 32.768KHz sinewave.

I tried powering the Arduino from my desktop's USB or from batteries and it doesn't make any difference.

**Edit:**

It sounds like radio noise when it's not tuned to any station basically.

And when it's tuning from one point to the other it's a different digital DJ sort of sound, I guess that's how it should sound.

I've probed the output of the chip directly before the amp and it looks like noise as well (flat FFT and looks like noise in the time domain as well).

The antenna is a ~50cm piece of a 30AWG wire-winding wire.

**Edit:** The resistance between the FM input (FMI) pin and ground measures to around 200K.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4J1gK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Edit:** The thin yellow wire is the antenna. The pin it's connected to the breadboard, I've cut it on the header.

[image: The whole setup]

[image: Breakout board close-up]

Comment: puh, "it's just noise" is sadly not very specific. Can you test, for example with the microphone input of a soundcard, whether the Si4735 really only outputs noise (maybe it's the opamp circuit, so maybe remove C5 for that test!)? If that's the case, the next easiest guess is the antenna. Do you have a picture /description of the antenna?

Comment: @MarcusMüller, I've added more details in the question.

Comment: Could you add a photo of the setup?  "Solderless breadboard" and "RF" seldom go together; we need to see exactly what is wired where.

Comment: @rdtsc, I've added the photos. I should also note that the resistance between the FM input pin and ground measure at around 200KOhm if that's important.

Comment: @rdtsc, I wonder if I killed the input of the LNA. Could a continuity measurement have damaged the LNA input? or from overheating when soldering or ESD?